# How To Dismiss Popover From Destination View Controller in Swift

Tags: swift, popover

I have a main view controller that has been setup in Interface Builder to open a table view controller via popover segue connected to a button. I want to be able to dismiss the popover when an item inside of my popover table view is selected in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In Objective-c I can just typecast the the segue in the `prepareForSegue delegate` to a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`and pass along its `UIPopoverController` to the table view controller. However, in Swift my downcast fails because it sees the segue as type `UIStorybaordPopoverPresentationSegue` (when stepping through with the debugger) which doesn't appear to be a public API.

Here's my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowCollectionsSegue" {
        if let collController:CollectionsTableViewController! = segue.destinationViewController as? CollectionsTableViewController {
            if let popoverSegue = segue as? UIStoryboardPopoverSegue { // <-- This fails
                collController.popover = popoverSegue.popoverController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I coerce the segue to a `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` in order to access its `popoverController` property?

I'm open to solving the problem of dismissing the popover in response to a table view cell tap a different way, but it seems that when using a segue from the storyboard, the only way to dismiss the popover is by holding onto a reference to the popover controller somehow and the only way to do that as far as I can tell is to cast the segue to a popover segue which Swift doesn't want to let me do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strange problem, indeed. I noticed in the documentation, that `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` does *not* inherit from any class. That explains why the cast does not work - `UIStoryboardSegue` is not its superclass. So I just tried to create a new object - it looks weird but works:

```
let popoverSegue = UIStoryboardPopoverSegue(
   identifier: segue.identifier, 
   source: self, 
   destination: segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController)
println("Is there a controller? \(popoverSegue.popoverController.description)")
// YES !!
```

**EDIT**

But this controller will not dismiss the popover :(

The fix is to specify the segue in Interface Builder as "Deprecated Segues : Popover". Then the code would be as expected

```
let popoverSegue = segue as  UIStoryboardPopoverSegue
if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewController {
   destination.delegate = self
   self.popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate it. That seems to create a valid popover segue with popoverController, however, when I go to dismiss the popover after having assigned it to my destination view controller's property using `self.popover!.dismissPopoverAnimated(true)`, it fails to dismiss it.

Comment: Something I just noticed... if you command click the `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` it will take you to the Swift "header". In there it appears that `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue` does inherit from `UIStoryboardSegue`.

Comment: OK, I could fix it by setting the type of popover to "Deprecated Segues : Popover" in IB. Sorry there is no solution for Adaptive Segues yet.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, for me. Are you saying that you just change it to the popover instead of the adaptive popover and it works with the code you provided?

Comment: No, of course I am not creating a new popover controller with this. Rather, I keep an ivar to hold a reference to the popover controller. See the edit above.

Comment: Cool. That'll work for now. I'll check back on this with the next Xcode 6 release since this issue is in the GM seed. Thanks for your help.